# How do I select the foot in numeric paging? RadGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, footer, radgrid

I currently have a js function that binds onchange to onbeforeunload or a confirmbox only if there are changes on the grid.

I am trying to select the footer paging anchors so that it doesn't trigger for confirm or onbeforeunload. The user should select the numeric paging regardless if there are changes or not on the grid.

There is no ID or class name on the anchors so I'm having trouble accessing it.

Thanks in advance.

RadGrid properties:

```
             <telerik:RadGrid 
             runat="server" 
             ID="DataGridFooItems" 
             AllowSorting="true" 
             AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
             EnableViewState="True" 
             GridLines="Vertical" 
             AllowPaging="True" 
             PagerStyle-Mode="NumericPages">

             <MasterTableView 
             AllowPaging="true" 
             DataKeyNames="foopersonID,fooItemID" 
             AllowAutomaticDeletes="true" 
             CommandItemDisplay="None" 
             NoMasterRecordsText="" >
```

This is what the .aspx generates below:

```
    <TFOOT>
<TR class=rgPager>
<TD colSpan=20>
<TABLE style="WIDTH: 100%" border=0 cellSpacing=0>
<TBODY>
<TR>
<TD class="rgPagerCell NumericPages">
<DIV class="rgWrap rgNumPart">
<A class=rgCurrentPage onclick="returnfalse;"href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl02','')"><SPAN>1</SPAN></A><A 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl04','')"><SPAN>2</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl06','')"><SPAN>3</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl08','')"><SPAN>4</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl10','')"><SPAN>5</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl12','')"><SPAN>6</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl14','')"><SPAN>7</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl16','')"><SPAN>8</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl18','')"><SPAN>9</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl20','')"><SPAN>10</SPAN></A><A
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ph$FOO$rgItems$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl22','')"><SPAN>...</SPAN></A> 
</DIV></TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE></TD></TR></TFOOT>
```

**UPDATE: Answer!**

Found it! with some research and tweaking of a similar Telerik Solution.

I composed this:

1. I declared a variable which selected a class.
2. Then I searched through the object for all the anchors.
3. Afterwards, I used a loop through anchors if it is not on the
   current page(should not have a click event, since the user is
   already on the page.) && if the anchor has a href of __doPostback.
4. Then i set the attribute onclick event to a confirmation. This step
   wrapped the __doPostback.

Source: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-paging---pageindexchanged-event-issue.aspx

```
function preventPromptOnFooter() {

            var pagerCell = $('[class="rgPagerCell NumericPages"]')
            var anchors = $(pagerCell).find('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                if (anchors[i].className != "rgCurrentPage" && anchors[i].href.indexOf("javascript:__doPostBack") > -1) {
                    var clickScript = anchors[i].attributes["onclick"].value;
                    anchors[i].onclick = disableOnbeforeUnloadForFooter;
                }
            }



            function disableOnbeforeUnloadForFooter() {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Um you shouldnt be putting divs inside a td tag

Comment: I believe this is auto-generated by the telerik RadGrid. Unless I'm missing something. I didnt' intentionally put the div's in there like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! with some research and tweaking of a similar Telerik Solution.

I composed this:

1. I declared a variable which selected a class.
2. Then I searched
       through the object for all the anchors.    anchors
3. Afterwards, I used a loop 
           through anchors  if it is not on the current page(should not have a
           click event, since the user is already on the page.) && if the
           anchor has a href of __doPostback.

   1. If step (3.) is true, it set the attribute onclick event to a confirmation. This step      wrapped the __doPostback.

Source:
http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-paging---pageindexchanged-event-issue.aspx

```
function preventPromptOnFooter() {

            var pagerCell = $('[class="rgPagerCell NumericPages"]')
            var anchors = $(pagerCell).find('a');
            for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
                if (anchors[i].className != "rgCurrentPage" && anchors[i].href.indexOf("javascript:__doPostBack") > -1) {
                    var clickScript = anchors[i].attributes["onclick"].value;
                    anchors[i].onclick = disableOnbeforeUnloadForFooter;
                }
            }



            function disableOnbeforeUnloadForFooter() {
                window.onbeforeunload = null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
var pageLinks = document.querySelectorAll(".rgWrap.rgNumPart a");
```

Which works in Chrome, Firefox 3.5+, ie8+, Opera 10 and Safari 3.2+. If you have to support older browsers, you could try a combination of getting the parent div by its classname and then using getElementsByTagName('A'). Or use a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to implement advanced CSS selectors cross browser.

Comment: You need to use the html5 doctype for IE9 to work with the querySelectorAll() javascript method.

Comment: Thanks for the update and sorry I wasn't clear on the supported browsers. Unfortunately, we need to support older browsers so this solution is not compatible for me.